# Why is a pointer to a string stored in .rodata but a pointer to the int is on the stack?

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following questions related to the C language:

1. Why is `char *p="Harish"` stored in `.rodata` segment?
2. Why is `int *p=90` stored on the stack?

Comment: Your title says `.text` but your question says `.rodata`

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish the title is just to lure you in

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
char *p = "Harish";
```

you're doing the following:

1. You're creating a pointer on the stack, named `p`.
2. Initializing it to the address of the literal string `"Harish"`. This string has to be stored somewhere that won't go away when the function exits, so it's stored in the read-only data segment (it's a constant string, so it doesn't need to be writable).

By contrast, when you do this:

```
int *p = 90;
```

you're just creating a pointer, but not anything for it to point to. You're just setting the pointer to point to the address `90`. As in the above case, the pointer is in the stack. Nothing goes into the `.rodata` segment because the declaration doesn't create anything for it to point to.

Comment: I don't know if `int* p = 90` is valid in C.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but the consequences of using the pointer are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *p="Harish"
```

In the above line “Harish” is stored in a shared read only location. but pointer p is stored in a read-write memory. You can change p to point something else but cannot change value at present p. So this kind of string should only be used when we don’t want to modify string at a later stage in program.